# config.xml location in Cordova vs PhoneGap Build

Tags: xml, cordova, phonegap-build

I have installed Cordova on my Mac and developed an app. It is structured as follows:

> - config.xml
> - www
>
>   - index.html
>   - index.js
> - cordova
> - plugins
> - platforms

Note how config.xml is placed outside of the *www* folder.

Now, for using Phonegap Build, the config.xml must be placed next to the index.html. This makes it really inconvenient to switch between the two tools.

Is there any way I can *teach* Phonegap Build to look for the index.html file inside *www* folder, not next to config.xml?

Comment: Added my own solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building a project, Cordova first looks for `config.xml` in the project root folder, then in the `/www/` folder, then in the `/platform/android/assets/www` or `/platform/ios/[project_name]`.

So I just moved the config.xml from `root` into `/www/` and was able to successfully build projects, thereby unified the config file locations for local Cordova and Phonegap Build. Voilà!

Comment: This is probably the reason why my plugins are not loading. Thanks heaps.

Comment: maybe something has changed in almost three years? haven't tried this in a while

Comment: Very possible :)
In the end I found myself having a build task to copy it from the root location inside www folder to support both local & remote builds.